# Ansible block rescue force fail with failed_when

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have the following block :

```
 - block:
     - name: "actions"
       ...   # some tasks
   rescue:
     - name: "Rollback"
       ...   # some tasks
     - name: "force fail after rollback"
       debug:
         msg: "this task is just to force a fail"
       failed_when: true     #tried yes instead of true too
```

Running this (using Rundeck), when rescue is called to rollback, we get success even with the force fail.

```
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
Host1 : ok=99   changed=41   unreachable=0    failed=1
localhost : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
Host2 : ok=99   changed=41   unreachable=0    failed=1

Playbook finished: Fri Feb  7 17:16:16 2020, 211 total tasks.  0:04:04 elapsed.
```

following the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html) :

***This will ‘revert’ the failed status of the task for the run and the play will continue as if it had succeeded.***

How can i force fail / failing the play in rescue block ?

Anisble version :

```
%$ ansible --version
ansible 2.6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *"Ansible block rescue force fail with failed_when"*

A: It works as expected with Ansible 2.9.4. The play below

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - block:
        - debug:
            msg: Block failed
          failed_when: true
      rescue:
        - debug:
            msg: Rescue started
        - debug:
            msg: Rescue failed
          failed_when: true
```

gives

```
PLAY [localhost] ***

TASK [debug] ***
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Block failed"
}

TASK [debug] ***
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Rescue started"
}

TASK [debug] ***
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Rescue failed"
}

PLAY RECAP ***
localhost: ok=1  changed=0  unreachable=0  failed=1  skipped=0  rescued=1  ignored=0
```

---

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.9.4
  config file = /home/tester/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/tester/.ansible/my_modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.16 (default, Oct  7 2019, 17:36:04) [GCC 8.3.0]
```

Comment: my bad, i have a meta: end_play inside my rollback role, can we force a failed on a meta task ?